# Is there a simpler way to perform this query

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is that query (MySQL syntax):

```
select
  id_image
from
  (
    select
        id_image
      , count(id_image) as nb
    from
      data
    group by
      id_image
  ) temp_table
where
  nb = (select count(distinct id_group) from data)
```

- data is a table of 3 columns: int id_user, int id_group and int id_image
- A row (x, y, z) means that:

  - image z is in image group y
  - group y was created by user x

And we want to list all the images that are present in each image group. Thanks.

Comment: I'd think `having` is the clause that could help you?

Comment: Just a remark: You table isn't normalized. You hold the groups' creators redundantly which can lead to data inconsistency. You should have one table for image groups and another for images. And one for the Image Group - Image relations, if an image can be in more than one group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are selecting all Image IDs that occur in data as often as there are distinct group IDs in that table? That seems strange.

Anyhow, the query can be re-written as:

```
select id_image
from data 
group by id_image
having count(*) = (select count(distinct id_group) from data);
```

Comment: Thank you all. It was about the `having` clause indeed. Thorsten, we want to list all the images that are present in each image group, i.e. images that appear nb times in data, where nb = the number of distinct groups. And yes id_user is not used here and it makes data not normalized, but it's a long story :).

Answer (score 0):

How about try this:

*select id_group, id_image from data where id_group in (select distinct id_group from data);*